# Prevent title bar animation when changing activities

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, titlebar

I am building an Android app which currently consists of a number of activities, each with a custom *LinearLayout* title bar at the top.

When I change the activity, the default animation results in the entire page sliding across, whereas ideally I'd like the title bar to stay static. As the title bar often contains the same text across multiple pages the animation seems unnecessary.

Spotify's Android app is a perfect example of what I mean. If you navigate to 'More' and click 'Settings', the page content slides across however the title bar doesn't.

If anybody has any insight it would be much appreciated!

*Title bar layout:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@layout/bg_menubar"
android:paddingLeft="14dp">

<TextView android:text="APP_NAME"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:shadowColor="#231f20"
    android:shadowRadius="1.6"
    android:shadowDx="1.5"
    android:shadowDy="1.3" />

<ImageView android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00113a"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp" />     
<ImageView android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#8b979f"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:text="Dashboard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:shadowColor="#231f20"
    android:shadowRadius="1.6"
    android:shadowDx="1.5"
    android:shadowDy="1.3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Android's in-built ViewFlipper class seems to be a good approach. That way I can bundle similar 'pages' into one activity. Still, it would be interesting to know if this would be possible with separate activities too!

Answer (score 1):

> whereas ideally I'd like the title bar to stay static

This is not possible, sorry.

> Spotify's Android app is a perfect example of what I mean. If you navigate to 'More' and click 'Settings', the page content slides across however the title bar doesn't.

Those aren't multiple activities, then. As @Preyes indicates, they are probably using `ViewFlipper`.